# Deliberately crashing an external process under Windows

Tags: windows, crash-dumps

I would like to synthesise a native code fault. This is so that we can see where in particular some debugging output gets put when that occurrs.

Pskill (from Sys-Internals) causes a graceful exit. DotCrash.exe doesn't seem to be available anymore from Microsoft directly.

Is there any way to externally cause a crash in a process?

Comment: Thanks for all the helpful comments. We're trying to debug behaviour in a Citrix environment and installing the Debugging Tools for Windows may be above my pay grade!

I'll see what the sys-admin has to say about it.

Comment: You don't need to install the Debugging tools. You can just install them on your developer PC any copy the "Debugging tools for windows" folder to the server. No installation required. (You should ask your sysadmin first anyway, though)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force crash an application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284913/force-crash-an-application)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done this before using windbg by:

1. Starting the process
2. Attaching to the process with windbg
3. Setting a breakpoint on one of my app's functions
4. Running the app until I hit the breakpoint
5. In windbg setting a local variable to something that will cause an Access Violation (e.g. set a pointer to 0xFFFFFFFF or muck with the register values)
6. hit f5 and the app should hopefully crash

Answer (score 2):

If what you want is the equivalent of a coredump, `drwtsn32 -p ProcessId` generates a dump of the current state of a running process. If you have the appropriate debug symbols you can get valuable information.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks for the tip... actually I was testing the exiting of the Java Virtual Machine which generates an `hs_err` file . We needed to capture that file when an organic quit happened. I wanted to deliberately fault the VM so we could inspect where the JVM decided to place the file.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using [CreateRemoteThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682437%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). Using it correctly isn't easy, but making the other process crash should be pretty easy ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As Nick mentions, this can easily be done via Debugging Tools for Windows - I'd go one step further though, and use cdb (the command-line WinDbg) to script the whole interaction.

Answer (score 1):

If you need dumps at any desired time, you can use Microsoft's free debug diagnostic tool which has a nice UI to do that or on command line `drwtsn32 -p processid` as recommended by jrbjazz.

Answer (score 0):

Could you install some kind of hook function, or use something like the [detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/) library?