# force any running process to crash

Tags: windows, testing, crash

I would like to crash a running program of my choice (e.g., notepad++, becrypt, word) for software testing purposes.

I know how to BSOD, I know how to cause a program I write to crash, I know how to end process - but how to crash an existing process I do not!

any help?

Comment: If this a program that you can attach a debugger then you can quit the debugger without detaching -  this will crash your application

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force crash an application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284913/force-crash-an-application)

Answer (score 8):

Well, use `CreateRemoteThread` on a remote process and invoke *something* [1] that crashes the process reliably. I'm not sure whether `CreateRemoteThread` guards against null pointers, but you could pass an address in the null page to it and have the remote process execute that.

[1] null pointer or null page access, division by zero, invoking a privileged instruction, `int3` ...

---

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <Windows.h>

BOOL setCurrentPrivilege(BOOL bEnable, LPCTSTR lpszPrivilege)
{
    HANDLE hToken = 0;
    if(::OpenThreadToken(::GetCurrentThread(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, FALSE, &hToken)
        || ::OpenProcessToken(::GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken))
    {
        TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;
        LUID luid;

        if(!::LookupPrivilegeValue(
            NULL,            // lookup privilege on local system
            lpszPrivilege,   // privilege to lookup 
            &luid ) )        // receives LUID of privilege
        {
            ::CloseHandle(hToken);
            return FALSE; 
        }
        tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
        tp.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
        tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = (bEnable) ?  SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED : 0;

        // Enable the privilege or disable all privileges.
        if(!::AdjustTokenPrivileges(
            hToken,
            FALSE,
            &tp,
            sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES),
            (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES) NULL,
            (PDWORD) NULL)
            )
        {
            CloseHandle(hToken);
            return FALSE; 
        }
        ::CloseHandle(hToken);
    }
    return TRUE;
}

int killProcess(DWORD processID)
{
    HANDLE hProcess = ::OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, processID);
    if(hProcess)
    {
        if(!setCurrentPrivilege(TRUE, SE_DEBUG_NAME))
        {
            _tprintf(TEXT("Could not enable debug privilege\n"));
        }
        HANDLE hThread = ::CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)1, NULL, 0, NULL);
        if(hThread)
        {
            ::CloseHandle(hThread);
        }
        else
        {
            _tprintf(TEXT("Error: %d\n"), GetLastError());
            ::CloseHandle(hProcess);
            return 1;
        }
        ::CloseHandle(hProcess);
    }
    return 0;
}

int __cdecl _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR *argv[])
{
    killProcess(3016);
}
```

Of course you'll want to adjust the PID in the call to `killProcess`. Compiled with WNET DDK and tested on 2003 Server R2.

The gist here is that we tell the remote process to execute code at address 0x1 (`(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)1`), which is inside the null page but not a null pointer (in case there are checks against that). The crud around the function, in particular `setCurrentPrivilege` is used to gain full debug privileges so we can do our evil deed.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how to do that with the `winapiexec` tool:

`winapiexec64.exe CreateRemoteThread ( OpenProcess 0x1F0FFF 0 1234 ) 0 0 0xDEAD 0 0 0`

Replace `1234` with the process id and run the command, the process will crash.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DLL injection technique](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4610/Three-Ways-to-Inject-Your-Code-into-Another-Proces) in order to inject your code into another process. Then in your injected code do something simple like abort() or division by zero.

Answer (score 1):

A two steps mechanism is needed:

1. inject the process to crash (using an injection library, using [Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/), using a Hook installation, etc..). What you choose depends on the time and knowledge you have and other preconditions (like credentials, anti-injection protection, size of the foot-print you want to leave..)
2. perform an invalid operation in the injected process (like int 2Eh, divide by null, etc..)