# How to crash the webview2 in wpf to generate a crash report?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, webview2

I have a webview running in wpf. How can I crash only the webview processess to generate a crash dump on Windows?

I am open to doing this in the C# code or via an external api. I tried trying to crash the process using the following code:

```
System.Environment.FailFast("Error happened")
```

but it seems to exit the entire application not only the webview2 processes and doesn't seem to inovoke the [CoreWebView2.ProcessFailed Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.processfailed?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.2210.55).

I also tried doing as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63341966) answer to crash the process externally but getting an error: `The term 'OpenProcess' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,`. Not being a C++ expert I'm unable to follow other answers.

Comment: You can just get one of the `Microsoft Edge WebView2` processes you see in TaskManager, get that Process by ID and use `[Process].Kill()` to terminate it. That will raise the `ProcessFailed` event

Comment: Already tried that, but it doesn't generate a crash dump report

Comment: [MiniDumpWriteDump](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minidumpapiset/nf-minidumpapiset-minidumpwritedump)

Comment: @jimi do you mean that we have to manually write the crash dumps to the file and it will not be done automatically?

Comment: You can probably setup [User-Mode Dumps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wer/collecting-user-mode-dumps). The requested dump Type is the same as the [MINIDUMP_TYPE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minidumpapiset/ne-minidumpapiset-minidump_type) you found in the previous documentation. You can also attach a Debugger that provides this functionality, or use [ProcDump](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procdump)

Comment: Note that everything uses `MiniDumpWriteDump` in the end -- In relation to User-Mode Dumps, read carefully the first paragraph there (in relation to WER)

Comment: `Chromium` has a number of different options for triggering crashes for testing purposes, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you want to do this to test your logging in the event? As Jimi suggested you can kill one of the WebView2 processes used by your application and the event will be raised.

I would not recommend using this code in production, but here is an example.

```
var currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
var wv2Processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("msedgewebview2");

foreach (var process in wv2Processes) 
{
    //Make sure its one that belongs to our application!
    var parentProcessId = GetParentProcessId(process.Id);

    if (parentProcessId == currentProcess.Id)
    {
        process.Kill(); //This will cause the CoreWebView2 ProcessFailed event to fire
        return;
    }
}
```

and the method to get the parent process.

```
int GetParentProcessId(int processId)
{
    using (var process = Process.GetProcessById(processId))
    using (var query = new ManagementObjectSearcher($"SELECT ParentProcessId FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessId = {processId}"))
    using (var queryCollection = query.Get())
    {
        foreach (var mo in queryCollection)
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(mo["ParentProcessId"]);
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Hopefully this is useful!

EDIT:

It appears I over complicated it and a process ID is already provided by the web view instance.

```
var processToKill = Process.GetProcessById((int)webView.CoreWebView2.BrowserProcessId);
processToKill.Kill();
```

Answer (score 0):

`Chromium` has build-in urls for testing purposes, I believe `Edge Chromium` also supports these Urls. Quick test with `WebView2` shows they work as expected. There are a number of different options (I'm only listing a subset of them here).

- Browser process crash: `edge://inducebrowsercrashforrealz`
- Renderer process crash: `edge://crash`
- GPU process crash: `edge://gpucrash`
- Out of memory: `edge://memory-exhaust/`

You should be able to load `edge://crashes` in a browser instance to see all the crash reports generated.

**TIP**: Test with crashing the render process and GPU process first before you go crashing the browser process.